# awk: print quotes when input CSV may or may not have them

Tags: csv, awk

I'm using `gawk` and its `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"` feature, to parse CSV files, which may or may not have individual values wrapped within quotes.  (I don't think any values themselves have quotes within, but they do frequently have commas.)

The resulting output will be SQL (for sqlite3), so, I need to ensure that all text values are quoted.  However, if I simply quote all values from the input when printing into output, then those values that were also quoted within the original CSV file end up having double double-quotes, and things don't work.

**How do I remove the double quotes with awk from the individual fields (only to unconditionally add them later on when printing the output)?**  **Or only print the quotes conditionally in the first place?**

Comment: Heh, I've since found that there is actually an example at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check each field. Like:

```
BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
        if (substr($i,1,1)!="\"")
            $i="\""$i"\""
        print $i
    }

}
```

For example input:

```
adf," asdfas, d",adsf
4,5," dafs"
```

The output is:

```
"adf"
" asdfas, d"
"adsf"
"4"
"5"
" dafs"
```

**Update**

To only print a set of columns:

```
BEGIN { 
    FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    a="1 3"
    n=split(a,b," ")
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        r=$(b[i])
        if (substr(r,1,1)!="\"")
            r="\""r"\""
        print r
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, there are about a hundred columns, but I'm interested in less than a dozen.  Is there a way to make this conversion specifically only for those fields of interest?  I.e. do an `if` loop only for a set of numbers?

Comment: @cnst Yes, just list the columns you are interested in an array for instance. Let's say `a` contains the column numbers: then `for (i in a)` will loop over only those columns..

Comment: @cnst I have updated my answer with a suggestion.. Just list the columns in the string `a` in the `BEGIN` block..

Comment: Thanks!  But why did you use a regular for loop, instead of the one you suggested in the comment?

Comment: so, how would one use the `for (i in a)` syntax?

Comment: @cnst A little bit more cumbersome: Then you have to do `a[1]=1; a[2]=3; ... ; a[10]=80` for instance (in the `BEGIN` block).

Comment: `split("1 3 ... 80",a,/ /)` would do that. That's exactly what you have with `b[]` in your script right now. I think the real answer is that `for (i in b)` would re-order the fields in some "random" fashion.